# Explicit `this->` in member functions

Tags: c++

I have seen recommended that member functions refer to member variables using `this->` explicitly, to avoid forgetting to declare the member variable and accidentally referring to a global variable. Can anyone comment if they think this is a reasonable precaution or unnecessary verbosity that will needlessly complicate the reading of the code? Does anybody actually do this in day-to-day real-life programming?

Comment: IMO, this is an insane idea, nearly certain to do a great deal of harm to readability all the time, to ensure against a problem that I (for one) have never seen (though I have only written C++ for ~30 years, so maybe I just haven't seen it *yet*).

Comment: @JerryCoffin C++ first appeared in '83, so it would be hard to code in it for 30 years ;)

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz: Ooops -- typo. That should say "20 years". Sorry.

Comment: I think the accepted answer validates this question.  It's not just a style issue.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since I'm frequently implementing class templates, I'm used to always qualify member variables and member functions with `this->`. In the context of class templates there is another reason why it is useful to qualify names with `this->`: Names not depending on template arguments are looked up only in phase I look-up, i.e., names in base classes depending on template arguments are never looked up in the base. By qualifying member names with `this->` they become dependent. For example:

```
#include <iostream>

void f() { std::cout << "::f()\n"; }

template <typename T>
class base
{
public:
    void f() { std::cout << "base::f()\n"; }
};

template <typename T>
class derived
    : public base<T>
{
public:
    void g() {
        f();
        this->f();
    }
};

int main()
{
    derived<int>().g();
}
```

I'm using qualification with `this->` in all my code unless some coding guidelines prohibits me from doing so (and I'd consider this aspect of the coding guideline silly and wrong). Of course, in my own code I qualify all names which can be qualified and which aren't a customization point (e.g., I wouldn't qualify `swap()`).

Comment: Output is
```::f() (newline)
base::f() (newline)
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, no, since you don't normally use global variables that often, with names that would cause conflicts. Besides, you can always use a prefix to denote member variables:

```
class C {
    int m_Foo;
    int mBar;
};
```

Using this can really blow up the code size and affect readability. Consider

```
class Foo {
    int a, b, c, d;

    int Bar () {
        return (a + b + (b / c) + d * (c + a));
    }
};
```

Try adding `this->` in above example.

Also, every good editor will color the variable differently, depending on its scope.

Comment: Which editors color by scope? I am using VS2010, and it doesn't do this.

Comment: VS 2012, for example. Or you can just get VisualAssist addon.

Comment: That's assuming you are looking at the line in a code editor.

If you are debugging remotely in a console (which may not even support color, by the way), syntax highlighing cannot be relied upon to convey this information.

Your only options at that point are to resort to name obfuscation to identify member variables, or else to explicitly use this->.

Answer (score 1):

While some convention for member variables is a good thing, I think `this->` is too verbose, and tries to solve a problem with a rare chance to happen. I use `m_var` or `mVar` for member variables.

It reminds me this pseudo precaution `if (3 == var)` insead of `if (var == 3)` to avoid the mistake of `if (var = 3)`. Which nowdays compilers always catch.

A readable code counts. It prevents bugs.

Comment: +1, i always wondered why some old school C++ coders i used to work with wrote `if (3 == var)`...

Comment: I've tried to write it this way, but it's just... illogical? Compilers also warn about these expressions.

Comment: It's a few years now that I meet this thing here and there, and still not used to it.

Comment: I think `this->var` is a lot more readable than `m_var`. It's basically just trading one prefix for another, except that one of them actually bears meaning to the language.

Comment: I prefer using a postfix over an prefix (var_ or var_m instead of m_Var or mVar), easier to type (autocomplete can catch up sooner too, because you don't have to type m_ everytime) and you can still understand it. But I'm not a big fan of prefix/postfix anyway.

Answer (score 1):

`this->` is often used to avoid mixup with globals or parameters of member functions

- for the code maintainer when reading
- for autocompletion in IDEs

you can have these advantages also by prefixing members with `m_`
the prefix is less verbose