# Specializing member functions for templated container class

Tags: c++, template-specialization

I've written a templated container class MyCont:

```
#include <iostream>
template <class T>
class MyCont
{
    public:
        void SomeFunc();
        T* list;
};

template <class T>
void MyCont<T>::SomeFunc()
{
    std::cout<<"in function"<<std::endl;
    //...
}


int main()
{
    MyCont<int> y;
    y.SomeFunc();
    MyCont< MyCont<int> > x;
    x.SomeFunc();
}
```

This works fine. However in the case of a MyCont having MyCont as it's type, I would like to be able to change the behaviour of SomeFunc().
I'm not sure how to do this (or even if it's possible). I've tried adding this below the first definition of SomeFunc():

```
template <>
void MyCont< MyCont<class T> >::SomeFunc()
{
    std::cout<<"in altered function"<<std::endl;
    //...
}
```

This compiles, but it is always the first SomeFunc that is called

Thanks

Comment: I think you need full specialization of the class.  Oh and `free` types go in `template<>` at the start of the specialization.

Answer (score 0):

That's actually kind of in interesting case. I guess you meant to write

```
template <class T>
void MyCont< MyCont<T> >::SomeFunc()
{
    std::cout<<"in altered function"<<std::endl;
    //...
}
```

which would fail to compile. Instead, you wrote

```
template <>
void MyCont< MyCont<class T> >::SomeFunc()
{
    std::cout<<"in altered function"<<std::endl;
    //...
}
```

outside of your class, so the `class T`, which is misplaced, forward-declares a type `T`. This means that the compiler generates a function for a specialization of `MyCont` which does not exist and which is therefore not used.

To see what I mean, add the following specialization right after the main template:

```
template <class T>
struct MyCont< MyCont<T> > : MyCont<T>
{
    void SomeFunc();
};
```

which, together with the first, fixed version will now be called. Without a specialization of the class you can not achieve what you are looking for.

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/133635d9b7f111ae)

Comment: I actually tried what is in the first box to begin with. When it failed I experimented around till I found something that compiled but didn't work. What you suggested worked, thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: I have a question about your solution. It seems that in the altered SomeFunc(), I need to access all the members of MyCont by dereferencing the this pointer. In the live example you linked, entering list=0 on line 28 compiles fine, but to enter it on line 21 will fail unless you use this->list=0. Is there a reason for this?

Comment: @user2849689 Yes, there is a reason. Since in the specialization you *inherited* `list`, you need to use `this->` as it needs to be a dependent expression which is looked up during phase 2. Without it, it is looked up during phase 1 in the global namespace and that is not what you want. [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13674643/explicit-this-in-member-functions/13674722#13674722) might help you to understand 2-phase-lookup in C++.

Comment: Inheriting from `MyCont<T>` seems like a very specific and strange thing to do: why is it justified in this case?

Comment: @Yakk It is justified because it was just meant as an example to help understand what is happening and to explain what is possible and what isn't. I did not intent to suggest it "solves" the problem, because there is no direct solution to what the OP is trying to achieve. If you re-read the last paragraph of my answer and look at how I worded it, it is hopefully clear.

Answer (score -1):

You must partially specialize template with complete type only, to allow compiler generate separate code for each type, this modified example works as you expect, however it doesn't look so flexible anymore (strict MyCont T=int binding):

```
#include <iostream>
template <class T>
class MyCont
{
    public:
        void SomeFunc();
        T* list;
};

template <class T>
void MyCont<T>::SomeFunc()
{
    std::cout<<"in function"<<std::endl;
    //...
}

template <>
void MyCont< int >::SomeFunc()
{
    std::cout<<"in altered function"<<std::endl;
    //...
}

int main()
{
    MyCont<int> y;
    y.SomeFunc();
    MyCont< MyCont<int> > x;
    x.SomeFunc();
}
```